how to use the chrome for testing? I have downloaded both the chrome driver and chrome browser for testing, not sure where to place the chrome.exe
I have downloaded chrome driver 126.0.6478.182 from https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/126.0.6478.182/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip and placed it in the python folder in C drive and mentioned the path in the environment variables.
I have also downloaded the matching chrome browser for testing 126.0.6478.182 from https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/126.0.6478.182/win64/chrome-win64.zip. I am not sure how I can use this version of chrome for automation testing purpose. When I run this it opens the browser in the last version and fails after a minute.
Getting the following error:
WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: unable to send message to renderer
  (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)
  (Session info: chrome=131.0.6778.69)
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6E73C2775+28773]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6E732AFB0]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6E71C552A]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6E71B269C]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6E71B260C]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6E71B0CF8]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6E71B1BE7]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6E71D2DA8]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6E72580B3]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6E721296A]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6E7210B8D]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6E723EF9A]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6E720C1C6]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6E723F1B0]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6E725F1A4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6E723ED43]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6E720A548]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6E720B6B1]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6E76EF45D+3358029]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6E770430D+3443709]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6E76F83FD+3394797]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6E748929B+842635]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6E733654F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6E7331FA4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6E733213D]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6E7321629]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFCA3F14CB0+16]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFCA4E7ECDB+43]

I want to run the same chrome browser version as the web driver.

I have also placed the matching Chrome for testing 126.0.6478.182 in the same folder as chrome driver.
Edited:
Test Chrome ${cft} = set variable C:/Python311/chrome-win64/chrome.exe  ${cft_driver} = Set Variable C:/Python311/chromedriver.exe  ${options} = set variable binary_location="${cft}"; add_argument("start-maximized") open browser browser=Chrome options=${options} executable_path=${cft_driver} [Teardown] Close Browser

Got a different error now


You can use chrome driver with selenium in python for opening pages and getting content of page.

I am using robot framework and it was working fine until 2 days ago when I saw the google chrome was updated so I found that I can use the chrome for testing instead which will not auto update and I used the latest version for both browser and driver and it did not work. SO i tried to use the older version I was using for browser and webdriver, I have downloaded the older versions but it is still showing the last version of chrome browser instead of the one that I want to use, not sure how.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

For example, having the "Chrome For Testing" and "chromedriver.exe" downloaded to the local disk to "c:\opt\chrome_for_testing" folder:
${cft} =         set variable  C:/opt/chrome_for_testing/chrome-win64/chrome.exe
${cft_driver} =  Set Variable  C:/opt/chrome_for_testing/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe

${options} =     set variable  binary_location="${cft}";add_argument("start-maximized")

open browser   browser=Chrome  options=${options}  executable_path=${cft_driver}

It tested for the next versions:

robotframework-seleniumlibrary==6.6.1
selenium==4.25.0


Thanks Sam, tried that code and got the error (question updated with your code):
'ValueError: Unable to parse option: "add_argument("--start-maximized") executable_path=C:/Python311/chromedriver.exe"'
I took the executable_path=${cft_driver} part of the code out and it passed but still l running the last chrome version which is 131.0.6778.69.
ThoughI have downloaded is 126.0.6478.182 for both chrome and chrome driver.
I have uninstalled the regular chrome just to ensure that it is not somehow interfering and also I have deleted the version 131.0.6778.69 but it still is being used somehow.

I see that error put "add_argumet()" and "executable_path=..." together in the parsing error.
So, the draft guess that there is not enough spaces between them, could it be in your case? Just in case could you kindly try the example again, but  ensure that there are at least two spaces before "executable_path"

I tried that it still gave me the same error.

Could you somehow update your post with a screenshot of your code or as text but preserve all spaces as is in your IDE?

We updated pip from 24.0 -> 24.3.1

Robot framework upgraded from 6.1.1 to 7.0
Upgraded selenium from 4.15.2 to 4.4.3


I have also updated the question with the code and screenshots of code and error

Looking at the screenshot, I suspect there are two problematic places. 1. The next string should be one line: binary_location="${cft}";add_argument("start-maximized").  But you have two or more spaces before add_argument.
2. after browser=Chrome should be at least two spaces or more to separate arguments, but you have one
